# Controller ignoring _forward when compiler is on - is that desired behaviour?

Tags: error, controllers, overrides, compiler, extend

Simple example tested on magento 1.7.0.2

Created overloaded controller for Mage_Cms_IndexController

```
<routers>
  <cms>
<args>
  <modules>
    <My_Extension before="Mage_Cms">My_Extension</My_Extension>
  </modules>
</args>
  </cms>
</routers>
```

In my controller I have two methods

testOneAction and testTwoAction

I can confirm that they work my just going into /cms/index/testOne and /cms/index/testTwo

Now the fun part

Created third method

```
public function testThirdAction() {
    $this->_forward('testOne');
}
```

When compiler is DISABLED going into /cms/index/testThird I can see data from testOne

When compiler is ENABLED - got blank page

Even with display_errors, developer mode, full error reporting, there is absolutely nothing in magento logs, web server logs or php error logs.

Tried xdebug and it pointed me into direction that request is not marked as dispatched and then it dies silently.

What I found so far:
In includes/src/Varien_Autoload.php

```
/**
 * Register autoload scope
 * This process allow include scope file which can contain classes
 * definition which are used for this scope
 *
 * @param string $code scope code
 */
static public function registerScope($code)
{
    self::$_scope = $code;
    if (defined('COMPILER_INCLUDE_PATH')) {
        @include COMPILER_INCLUDE_PATH . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . self::SCOPE_FILE_PREFIX.$code.'.php';
    }
}
```

Looks like @ makes it to die silently, if I change it to include_once, everything works great

Anyone can help?

Answer (score 4):

This is a bug which is related with magento compiler. I will give you a short glance of what is actually happens here.

During compilation enabled, magento uses a copy of every files inside the directory `include/src`. Since every file have a corresponding copy in single directory and magento uses this single directory while coimpilation enabled, magento performs faster.

When you do `$this->_forward('testOne')`, magento now process router match processing one more time. As module didnt change, `Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action::preDispatch` method intents to make `Varien_Autoload` to load the the `include/src/Mage_Cms_IndexController.php` again. This is what failing here. Why it fails ? You have found out the answer. It is the bug which is present in `includes\src\Varien_Autoload::registerScope()`

```
static public function registerScope($code)
  {
    self::$_scope = $code;
    if (defined('COMPILER_INCLUDE_PATH')) {
      // Change to include_once to prevent including multiple times !!!
      //@include COMPILER_INCLUDE_PATH . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . self::SCOPE_FILE_PREFIX.$code.'.php';
      @include COMPILER_INCLUDE_PATH . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . self::SCOPE_FILE_PREFIX.$code.'.php';
    }
}
```

The last line of code is failing in this particular case. This is because, magento is trying to load the same `Mage_Cms_IndexController` which is avialble in `includes/src` when you perform a `_forward` action.

So if you use `include_once` instead of `include`, then it will resolve the issue.

For more info, **[use this](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/310970/)**